# Features available during training but not at prediction

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, cart, shapley-value

Broadly, my motivation is to understand if/how features available during training but not at prediction can be used to improve the prediction accuracy of a machine learning model. This question is about implementing a specific idea I wanted to test.

SHAP values are a measure of the contribution of each feature to the overall prediction of a machine learning model. The definition of SHAP values involves model predictions for every subset of features. For predictions from a tree-based model using a feature subset, my understanding of how this works is:

- At each node, if the feature at the node is in the subset, we proceed as usual.
- If the feature at the node is not in the subset, we assign a weight to the left and right child of that node, based on how the training data at that node divided into left and right.
- Rather than winding up with a single leaf node for each tree, we end up with a probability distribution on leaf nodes.  The prediction is then the weighted mean of the values at those leaf nodes.

`XGBoost` has built-in functionality to compute SHAP values (the `predict` method of a `booster` object is given the parameter `pred_contribs=True`). I am wondering: is there a way to get predictions for subsets of features from `XGBoost`, or from other tree-based models, apart from writing the whole calculation from scratch? I'm not positive whether `XGBoost` is actually computing these subset predictions as part of SHAP, or whether it is using some different heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

Your question relates to a few different and loosely-related concepts, so I'll try to address each of them.

(1)
In short, SHAP value of a feature $x_j$ is the average absolute contribution of this feature to the difference between the actual prediction $f(\cdot)$ and the expected prediction $E[f]$ (see [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-019-0138-9)):

$$\phi_j=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left|f\left(x^{(i)}_j\right)-E[f(X_j)]\right|$$

It's OK to take SHAP values as a measure of variable importance (kinda gold standard these days) but it's important to remember two things:

1. They don't account for feature interaction
2. They are relative - that is, changing the feature space might change the SHAP values

Once you have the SHAP values set for the full feature space you can obviously take only the relevant indices using vector operations in R/python, but if I understand you correctly then you are looking for the SHAP values when the model only has those features you think are important - in which case you need to train a new model with the feature subspace and then request the SHAP values.

---

(2)
If I understand correctly, you are looking for some kind of feature selection method. You can select a feature subspace based on SHAP values (not really sure what's the literature regarding this idea) but then you need to train a new model using that subspace

If you train a model on feature space $X_1,...X_p$ but use only a subspace of it and completing the remainder as weighted averages (like you described), not only you're violating the basic concepts of decision trees but to me (without doing the whole math) it looks as if you were contaminating the data with some randomly-drawn values in place of the dropped features. Which is my way of saying that it sounds totally crazy to me, but maybe I'm missing something there.

---

(3)
XGBoost is based on a large number of "meaningless" decision trees (each tree is short and not very accurate), which form a very strong ensemble when combined. That is unlike random forests, in which each of the trees is both long (/deep) and meaningful. Its importance values might differ greatly compared to other models, because in a way the meaninglessness of the trees makes the importance quite idiosyncratic. For example consider this plot of SHAP values for 5 different models in predicting Titanic survival:
[image: SHAP importance values for the Titanic data]

---

(4)
It's true that XGBoost models provide SHAP "on the house" but it's not that difficult for other models. In R there's the [fastshap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastshap/index.html) package (see [tutorial](https://bgreenwell.github.io/fastshap/articles/fastshap.html)) which is my personal favorite. I suppose similar packages are available for python as well.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer!

Comment on (2): I agree this process for dropped features is strange. But my belief was that this actually happens when SHAP values are computed for a decision tree. My motivation here is to understand what happens if I fit trees using some a large collection of features, then use this method to predict using a subset of features (imagining the subset represents only those features available at prediction time). My guess is that accuracy will be worse than simply fitting model to the subset of features, but I hope to run some experiments to confirm this.